# Combine Two Rows into One with Similar fields (DateTime) and NULL Vales in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Could any one help me for the below request.

I have data of One row for the Login DateTime and another row for the Logout Datetime. The rest of the fields are same. I need to combine both rows in to one with Login (Datetime) and Logout (Datetime).

Sample Data

```
ID  Code    DateTime    User    Status

35  100 1/1/2014 14:50  a   IN

35  100 1/1/2014 15:45  a   OUT

35  100 1/1/2014 18:20  a   IN

35  100 1/1/2014 19:10  a   OUT
```

Result should look like below

```
ID   Code  Datetime1           Datetime2           User

35   100   2014-01-01 14:50    2014-01-01 15:45    a

35   100   2014-01-01 18:20    2014-01-01 19:10    a
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds the next date/time with an 'OUT' after each 'IN' :
(simplified to match small data sample, extra code required)

```
With YourData as (
 SELECT 35 as ID, 100 as Code, '1/1/2014 14:50' as yDatetime,
   'a' as yUser, 'IN' AS status  UNION ALL
 SELECT 35,100, '1/1/2014 15:45', 'a', 'OUT' UNION ALL
 SELECT 35,100, '1/1/2014 18:20', 'a', 'IN'  UNION ALL
 SELECT 35,100, '1/1/2014 19:10', 'a', 'OUT'
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Code,
  yDatetime AS When_IN,
  (SELECT Min(yDatetime) FROM YourData yd2
   WHERE (yd2.yDatetime>YourData.yDatetime)
     AND Status='OUT'
     -- extra matching needed here
     -- for ID, CODE, User fields in use
  ) AS When_OUT,
  yUser as _User
FROM YourData WHERE Status='IN'
```

Results :
35  100 1/1/2014 14:50  1/1/2014 15:45  a
35  100 1/1/2014 18:20  1/1/2014 19:10  a

Comment: Same issue as the TOP subquery - performance will degrade significantly as rows are added due to having to rerun the subquery for each row...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function to determine the closest 'OUT' status for each 'IN' iteration:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.Code, t1.[Datetime] as Datetime1, tNext.[Datetime] as Datetime2, t1.[User],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID, t1.Code, t1.[User], t1.[Datetime] ORDER BY tNext.[Datetime]) rowNum
  FROM myTable t1
  JOIN myTable tNext ON
    t1.ID = tNext.ID AND 
    t1.Code = tNext.Code AND 
    t1.[User] = tNext.[User] AND 
    tNext.Status = 'OUT' AND
    t1.[Datetime] < tNext.[Datetime]
  WHERE t1.Status = 'IN' ) t
WHERE rowNum = 1
ORDER BY ID, Code, [User], Datetime1
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83d20/2)

Comment: I've given you an upvote for the solution that scales better by the looks of it - looks like the questioner favours the Keep It Simple approach for now though! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select
    a.id,
    a.code,
    a.datetime as datetime1,
    b.datetime as datetime2,
    a.user
from
    (select
        id,
        code,
        datetime,
        user
    from
        table
    where
        status='IN') a
inner join
    (select
        id,
        code,
        datetime,
        user
    from
        table
    where
        status='OUT') b
on
    (a.user=b.user and a.id=b.id and a.code=b.code)
```

Comment: What exactly do you think this does?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT lin.ID, lin.CODE, lin.USER, lin.DateTime as LoginDate,
   (select top 1 DateTime from TABLE lout 
    where lout.data > lin.data and lin.id=lout.id
          and lin.user = lout.user and lin.code = lout.code and status = 'out'
    order by lout.dateTime
) as LogOutDate
FROM TABLE lin
where lin.status='IN'
```

Comment: You're missing the `WHERE lin.status = 'IN'` (and some field escaping and typos), but otherwise this concept will work.  The only problem is that it will need to run the SELECT TOP subquery for each row, so it will become slow very quickly as rows are added to the table.  Windowing Functions are designed to do this type of operation much faster...

Comment: thanks PinnyM for suggestion. i have add status in. yes, probably your solution is better :-)